# Fckeditor removes empty tags! How to fix?

Tags: php, javascript, fckeditor

If you enter the code `<a href="/link"></a>`, FCKeditor will remove the tag.

Start an FCKEditor, go to source mode (in FCKEditor). Type in `<a href="bob"></a>` (note nothing in the contents area of the anchor), go to WYSIWYG mode. Go back to source mode and you see empty source.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those are valid links. A link must contain *something*.

If you want to place an anchor, use `<a name="bob">Bob</a>`

If you want to link to an anchor, use `<a href="#bob">Link to Bob</a>`

Comment: valid links or not - that's not the point. It will also strip out empty span tags.

Comment: the fact that I just need to insert an empty tag! this may be <div></div> and other..  I try this http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/2253    but no effects

Answer (score 1):

thanks to all, I fixed - in file js/fckeditorcode_gecko.js  comment all

```
if ( htmlNode.innerHTML.Trim().length == 0 && !htmlNode.name )
                        return false ;
```

Answer (score 0):

... if you have access to the settings, If I'm not mistaken you can tell editor to leave you code alone. If you don't have access to the settings, you might be out of luck.

EDIT: If you need any empty tag then DIV will work. Span won't but div will, found out today.

Comment: i have access, i try all config but no settings that fixed this, sorry for my bad english